# margin-top and marin-left from nowhere

Tags: html, css

In my html file I have header and inside it there is ul>li>a menu

```css
/* ****** */
:root {
    --primary: #32a852;
    --white: #fafafa;
    --black: #000000;
    --lightgrey: #c7c7c7;

    --menu-items: #333333;
    --mobile-menu: #4a4a4a;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.no-select {
    
}

/* Tags :) */
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: var(--primary);
}

/* Header */
.header {
    display: flex;
    background: var(--white);
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.menu-items {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    transform: translateY(30%);
}

.menu-items li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu-items li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--menu-items);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.32rem;
}

.company-logo {
    width: 50px;
}

.menu-on-off {
    display: none;
    width: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 530px) {
    .menu-on-off {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 3%;
    }
    .menu-items {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        background: var(--mobile-menu);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .menu-items li {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-items li a {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        color: var(--white);
    }
}

/* Header& */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Реткинский Мультисад</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="company-logo" alt="Logo">
        <div style="text-align: right;"><img src="img/menu.png" class="menu-on-off" alt="Menu" onclick="menutoggle();"></div>
        <ul class="menu-items">
            <li><a href="">Продукты</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Галерея</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="new.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But here is a thing
[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ923.png)

1st there is a little margin-left for the menu and second more serious problem margin-top and in not media query code I dont added margin-top or margin-left.
Happy new year from Armenia ;p. Interesting what details need stackoverflow? Interesting what details need stackoverflow? Interesting what details need stackoverflow? Interesting what details need stackoverflow?

Comment: Please show as more releavant code (or link to your page). From your snippet that's not possible to help you

Comment: have you resetted the body margin with: `body { margin: 0; }` already?

Comment: @tacoshy: it's not body margin

Comment: @pavel not all of it, the left margin could be. But to many of the code is missing to clearly tell.

Comment: @tacoshy yes I added margin 0 for body

Comment: Do you want whole css code?

Comment: @Python_Programmer: not whole CSS code, just relevant code snippet (eg. at jsfiddle.net), where we can see where the margin is taken. Or link to your site.

Comment: It is not on server so I will put the code (edit question)

Comment: Please post it on jsfiddle.net or codesandbox so people could see the whole project. as of right now with the code you provided, we can only speculate what could be the issue and we can't even test it as majority is missing.

Comment: @Lith sorry I have already updated (

Comment: `transform: translateY(30%)` makes the top space.

Comment: and the `margin-left` is actually caused by `padding` from header in class `.header` `padding: 5px;`

Comment: @pavel thanks nice russian guy (I know russian too), but what about margin-left ? )

Answer (score 0):

OK—a few minor changes here, but is working. Most have to do with element positioning.

```css
/* ****** */
:root {
    --primary: #32a852;
    --white: #fafafa;
    --black: #000000;
    --lightgrey: #c7c7c7;

    --menu-items: #333333;
    --mobile-menu: #4a4a4a;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.no-select {
    
}

/* Tags :) */
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: var(--primary);
}

/* Header */
.header {
    display: flex;
    background: var(--white);
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.menu-items {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-items li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu-items li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--menu-items);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.32rem;
}

.company-logo {
    width: 50px;
}

.menu-on-off {
    display: none;
    width: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 530px) {
    .menu-on-off {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 3%;
    }
    .menu-items {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        background: var(--mobile-menu);
        width: 100%;
        top: 28px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .menu-items li {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-items li a {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        color: var(--white);
    }
}

/* Header& */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Реткинский Мультисад</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="company-logo" alt="Logo">
        <div style="text-align: right;"><img src="img/menu.png" class="menu-on-off" alt="Menu" onclick="menutoggle();"></div>
        <ul class="menu-items">
            <li><a href="">Продукты</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Галерея</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="new.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```